# Pre-calc complex roots of unity help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a pretty brief understanding of how the roots of unity work. I need a little help on how to solve 2 questions.

1. The equation $$z^5 = i$$ has $5$ solutions. The unique solution in the third quadrant is $re^{i\theta}$, where $r > 0$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$. What is $(r, \theta)$?

For this question. I m thinking of graphing it or just plugging in a+bi for z. 
and

2. The equation $$z^3 = -2 - 2i$$ has $3$ solutions. What is the unique solution in the fourth quadrant? Leave the answer in rectangular form.

For this one, I think same idea as question 1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: oh Ok. Thanks for the introduction

Comment: Well for your first question, think of dividing the complex plane into 5 equal angles. Then taking unit vectors along those angles will get you the five fifth roots of unity.

Comment: See [roots of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers) on Wikipedia's de Moivre's Formula page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $\omega$ is 5th root of unity

$$\omega=e^\frac{2\pi i}{5}=\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}=
\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{4}+i\frac{\sqrt{10+2 \sqrt{5}}}{4}$$
Then equation
$$z^5=i$$
has 5 solutions
$$z_k=i\omega^{k-1},\quad k=1\ldots 5$$
2.
$$-2-2i=2^{3/2}e^{-\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$$
Then $$z=2^{1/2}e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}=2^{1/2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=1-i$$
is solution of equation
$$z^3 = -2 - 2i$$
 in the fourth quadrant.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the first question? I'm kind of confused.